# How to use "youtube-dl + ffplay" to play youtube videos?

Tags: ffmpeg

When I play the video using the code below, it plays normally.

youtube-dl   "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cqEp0Kr2kak"  -o  - | ffplay  -autoexit  -i -

But when I specify the video format to play, it downloads the video to the local instead of playing it. I just want to specify the video format to play the video instead of downloading it.

youtube-dl   -f  "bestvideo[height<=?480]+bestaudio/best"   "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cqEp0Kr2kak"  -o  - | ffplay  -autoexit  -

what should I do.